# How to use PMD violationSuppressRegex with Sonar?

Tags: configuration, sonarqube, pmd

PMD allows suppressing violations with the `violationSuppressRegex` property. See PMD documentation [Violation Suppress Regex](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/suppressing.html#Violation_Suppress_Regex).

For example for the [LooseCoupling Rule](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.5/rules/java/coupling.html#LooseCoupling).

Is there any way to use this functionality in Sonar?

**Example**

Suppress Loose Coupling violation for LinkedHashSet in PMD:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/coupling.xml/LooseCoupoing">
  <property name="violationSuppressRegex" value=".*'LinkedHashSet'.*"/>
</rule>
```

Where the violation message is something like:

```
You should not use 'LinkedHashSet' but an interface.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`violationSuppressRegex` is a new property in PMD 5.0. And Sonar uses PMD 4.3.

Looks like I'll have to wait [until Sonar upgrades PMD](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-26) :-(

Answer (score -1):

You might want to have a look at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin

Comment: violationSuppressRegex is used for switching off violations with a regex on the violation message. I don't think the Switch Off Violations Plugin can do that.

Comment: No, indeed. But could you please give a real life example?